# Hibernate Cascade Order, ID Generation and Bi-Directional Relationships

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

Consider the three following entities with teir respective relationships:

```
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected UUID id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Entry> entries = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="project_id")
    private Project project;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "event")
    protected Set<Entry> entries = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public class Entry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="project_id")
    private Project project;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="event_id", nullable=false)
    protected Event event;
}
```

Now I have a method that gets a project with events as input and will create entries and additional events from it. Afterward, they all should be saved.

The main challenges I discovered were:

- (1) As **the ID-Generation is in the Database**, I can not add them all to the project and then save the entries. To keep the bi-directional relationship in sync I need to save them first and then add, or save the project and cascade the entries after adding. Especially when I have a collection of entities that are already saved and entities which do not have a PK yet, I need to clear set the whole collection new, or save the entities before adding them.
- (2) **No cascading order**: When Trying to save the project and cascading the entries, the child entities can not have interdependent relationships. E.g. what if it tries to save the entries before the events are saved? I could not find any option to set a cascade order.
- (3) **The Bi-directional relationship** between the entry-event also needs to be kept in sync. However, some events are newly added while others are already existing and saved, for the newly added ones we need to keep care of (1).

The question is: How to do this best?

I could save entities at creation time, but then I would have a single transaction at each creation. Alternatively I could keep them all in a result object and save them in the end, then afterwards add them to the project and save the project. However, both this options als do not make much use of the cascade option and are rather complex in that they add temporal dependencies. (first save X then Y, then Z)

---

Update: Code how I currently add the entities and save them to the project

The project has helper methods, that solely set the entries (could set bidirectional relation, but Project is not allowed to be null at creation of an entry/event):

```
public void addEntries(Collection<Entry> entries){
        this.entries.addAll(entries);
    }


    public void addEvents(Collection<Event> events){
        this.events.addAll(events);
    }


    public void addEntry(Entry entry){
        this.entries.add(entry);
    }


    public void addEvent(Event event){
        this.events.add(event);
    }
```

Currently I am saving the events at creation and the entries after the simulation function. The project is always saved at the very end after all operations.

```
    public ADEvent createADEvent(Round round) {
        ADEvent event = new ADEvent(round);
        event = saveDB ? eventRepository.save(event) : event;
        round.getProject().addEvent(event);
        return event;
    }

    public void saveEntries(Project project, Collection<Entry> entries) {
        if (saveDB) entries = entries.stream().map(entryRepository::save).collect(Collectors.toList());
        project.addEntries(entries);
    }

    public Project saveProject(Project project) {
        return saveDB ? projectRepository.save(project) : project;
    }
```

Updates are done the same way, just that I clear the whole collection in the project initially before running the simulation method. (and remove all simulation events)

Comment: can you provide code how you are adding entries and events to existing project and saving it ( with info which entities are persisted and which are newly created)

Comment: Added the methods how I save it currently. Especially the adding of events is not very good, as it saves them each in a separate transaction at creation time and then adds it to the project with the generated ID.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't save every entity separately. Problems may not occur if saving altogether with project. Cascading is defined correctly, I was able to add them all and save `project`. Just make sure both sides of relation are set up

```
    Project p = new Project();
    Entry ntry = new Entry();
    Event event = new Event();

    p.getEntries().add(ntry);
    ntry.setProject(p);// set also other side of relation
    ntry.setEvent(event);

    p.getEvents().add(event);
    event.setProject(p);// set also other side of relation
    event.getEntries().add(ntry);

    em.persist(p);
```